# Transform 3D points to 2D

Tags: math, matrix, 3d

I have a set of points (x1, x2,..xn) that lie on the plane define by Ax+ By+Cz+d=0.
I would like to find the transformation matrix to translate and rotate to XY plane. So, the new point coordinate will be x1'=(xnew, ynew,0).

A lot of answer give quaternion, dot or cross product matrix. I am not sure which one is the correct way.

Thank you

Comment: It seems to me like there's no single transformation matrix — you've no idea about rotation around the surface normal (A, B, C). If your surface were a post-it on a pin (with the pin being the surface normal) and I rotated the post-it without moving the pin, that wouldn't be recorded. So are you just looking for any transform that preserves distances and angles? Or e.g. have you a specific pair of points that you know are both on the x axis?

Answer (score 8):

First of all, unless in your plane equation, d=0, there is no [linear transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_transformation) you can apply.  You need to instead perform an [affine transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation).

One way to do this is to determine an angle and vector about which to rotate to make your pointset lie in a plane parallel to the XY plane (ie. the Z component of your transformed pointset to all have the same values).  Then you simply drop the Z component.

For this, let **V** be the normalized plane normal for the plane containing your points.  For convenience define from your plane equation above Ax+By+Cz+d=0:

```
V = (A, B, C)
V' = V / ||V|| = (A', B', C')
Z = (0, 0, 1)
```

where

```
A' = A / ||V||
B' = B / ||V||
C' = C / ||V||
||V|| = (A2+B2+C2)1/2
```

The angle will simply be:

```
θ = cos-1(Z∙V / ||V||)
  = cos-1(Z∙V')
  = cos-1(C')
```

The axis **R** about which to rotate is just the cross product of the normalized plane normal **V'** and **Z**. That is

```
R = V'×Z
  = (B', -A', 0)
```

You can now use this angle / axis pair to build the [quaternion rotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_rotation) needed to rotate all of the points in your dataset to a plane parallel to the XY plane.  Then, a I said earlier, just drop the Z component to perform an orthogonal projection onto the XY plane.

*Update:*  antonakos makes a good point about normalizing the **R** before using an API taking axis / angle pairs.

Comment: A sign issue: `R = V' × Z`, not `R = Z × V'`. Also it might be worth noting that many axis/angle APIs require `R` to be normalized (which it isn't yet).